# Use SYS_REFCURSOR with CTE (includes Update statement)

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression, toad

I am using CTE to fetch some values and then using UPDATE statement to clear the returned values from database table.

This is happening inside a stored procedure.

```
UPDATE TABLE1
   SET AA = NULL, BB = NULL
 WHERE EXISTS
          (WITH T1 AS (SELECT AA, BB, CC FROM TABLEABC)
               ,T2
                AS (SELECT AA, BB, CB
                      FROM T1
                     WHERE T1.AA > 100)
           SELECT *
             FROM T2
            WHERE TABLE1.CC = T2.CC
```

My column BB has some identification data which I want to capture before it is cleared by the Update statement. Can anyone guide me on how I can capture this column data and return as Procedure output.

```
OPEN SYS_REFCURSOR FOR
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `RETURNING INTO` clause of an `UPDATE` statement will give you the values *after* the update, not the prior values.

So, if you want to save off the old values, you must do so before the `UPDATE` statement.  Take care to lock the rows and only actually update rows that you've saved, because it is possible that your table could be modified between the time you save off the data and the time to update it.

Then, return the saved data in a ref cursor.

Here is code that puts that all together:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 ( AA number, BB number );

CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE so_test AS

  TYPE TABLE1_LIST_TAB IS TABLE OF TABLE1%ROWTYPE;

  FUNCTION do_it return sys_refcursor;

END so_test;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY so_test AS

  FUNCTION do_it RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
    l_old_data TABLE1_LIST_TAB;
    l_rc SYS_REFCURSOR;
  BEGIN

    SELECT AA, BB 
    BULK COLLECT INTO l_old_data
    FROM table1
    WHERE -- put your conditions here of what you intend to update
    FOR UPDATE;

    UPDATE TABLE1
      SET AA = NULL, BB = NULL
    WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 'record old data is captured'
                 FROM   TABLE(l_old_data) od
                 WHERE  od.aa = table1.aa   -- Assuming AA is a primary key
               ) 
    RETURNING AA, BB BULK COLLECT INTO l_old_data;

    OPEN l_rc FOR SELECT * FROM TABLE(l_old_data);

    RETURN l_rc;

  END do_it;
END so_test;
```

NOTE: if you are not on 12c, you will need to define `TABLE1_LIST_TAB` as an `OBJECT` type in the database instead of in the package spec, or else the package body won't compile.